# TypeError: Cannot read property 'webContents' of null in Electron-dl

Tags: javascript, npm, electron, dom-events

I want to download the file and save it to the desired folder but every time I am getting the below error.

#### Main.js

```
ipcMain.on('download-file', function (event, data) {
    console.log(data);
    download(BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(), data.url, {
        directory: "G:\\Orders\\"
    }).then(function (dl) {
        console.log(dl.getSavePath());
    }).catch(console.error);
});
```

#### Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'webContents' of null
    at Promise (G:\fc-electron\node_modules\electron-dl\index.js:125:22)
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports.download (G:\fc-electron\node_modules\electron-dl\index.js:122:47)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (G:\fc-electron\main.js:53:9)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at WebContents.<anonymous> (G:\fc-electron\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\browser\api\web-contents.js:249:13)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at WebContents.emit (events.js:213:7)
```

Any helpful answer will be appreciated.

Comment: You should open the debug view on your browser.

Comment: I am using electron

Comment: Assume no one knows what electron is. What have you done to solve this yourself? What about something like https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-debug or  https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process or 
 https://www.sitepoint.com/debugging-electron-application/

Comment: I've noticed the same error when using `electron-dl` downloader. It fails when the electron app loses focus when it's in the middle of a download such as when you click another app, or file explorer.

Comment: Like I said, `getFocusedWindow()` returns null if app loses focus. In my case, since I only have one window open during download, I was able to replace `BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()` with `BrowserWindow.getAllWindows()[0]` and the error went away even when the app loses focus. The reason I don't want to put this as answer is that it won't always work if you have more than 1 window open and the window in question is not at index 0 of the array.